# cross platform C++ library/libraries to: display a window, render 2D shapes on the screen, render text on the screen

Tags: c++, 2d

Can anyone recommend a set of C++ libraries to do the above? I've tried several things and have had problems with all of them, but rather than going into it all, I'm more interested in an unbiased recommendation on some good technologies for this. I'd give preference to simplicity over performance, in general.

Comment: SFML is a c++ lib, however SDL is more prolific. Depends how many platforms you actually need. Likely SDL has way more than you care about.

Comment: @monkey FWIW, I've tried both (SFML and SDL). SMFL has a nice API and seems like it should do everything I want, but I was having issues getting it to render things properly on my system (resizing my window would kind of mess everything up, for one). SDL works alright for rendering shapes (would prefer not to revert to manually making GL calls, but w/e), and for rendering fonts separately, but I've yet to get both working in the same app.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/topics-ui.html) and it's [QGLWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/qglwidget.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenGL for graphics, U++ for GUI](http://www.ultimatepp.org/reference%24OpenGL%24en-us.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider looking [wxWidget + OpenGL](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/opengl.htm)